# Is there any way that I can turn this into a list comprehension

Tags: python, optimization, list-comprehension

I often find myself doing inefficient loops as such:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    dimensions = []
    for i in range(max(self.numberOfDimensions, other.numberOfDimensions)):
        a = None    
        if i < self.numberOfDimensions:
            a = self[i]     
        b = None    
        if i < other.numberOfDimensions:
            b = other[i]    

        # Doesn't actually do the right thing here.
        dimensions.append(sum(map(lambda x: ((x is None) and 1 or 2) - 1, (a, b))))

    return self.__class__(dimensions)
```

The calculation is simple, it's just handling the if statements types that's getting me. By the way, this is a subclass of tuple in which the add operator adds similar index's values like so `(1, 2, 3) + (4, 5, 6, 7) == (5, 7, 9, 7)`. I would think that `filter()` would help me out on this but I'm not sure how I'd implement it.

EDIT: This is for Python 3.

Comment: Are you sure the line `dimensions.append(sum(map(lambda x: ((x is None) and 1 or 2) - 1, (a, b))))` does what you think it does?  It's a rather strange way of writing `dimensions.append(a is not None + b is not None)`, which is already strange enough.

Comment: Quick check, does this fall under premature optimization? It is easy for you, and others, to understand this for loop. Is it actually causing large slowdowns in your program, and if so, do you care? If it triples the runtime from 50 nanoseconds to 150 nanoseconds, you won't even notice.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun: It is definitely *not* easy to understand this code, as demonstrated as a bunch of answers doing a diversity of different things.

Comment: @Spencer, possibly. I don't know who will be using the class and what it will be used for. I'm about to run some benchmarks to test the differences.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, my mistake, you are right. That's something I overlooked. I never finished the definition of the function as you can see there is no `return` statement.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I was assuming that within the program's context the code made sense. If it needs to be to be clearer, condensing it into one very long statement just makes it worse. You have to unroll it mentally, instead of having it laid out. But that's a separate, documentation issue.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun: Yes, got the point.  But my guess is this code is supposed to perform the simple addition operation described in the post.  It doesn't, of course, but even if it did, it would be a quite obfuscated way of doing it. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach, exactly. I figured there was simpler way to add the numbers like as described.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: The comment wasn't meant pejoratively -- I just meant to explain to Spencer why I don't consider this premature optimisation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, and I didn't take it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most concise way to do this is

```
map(sum, itertools.izip_longest(self, other, fillvalue=0))
```

or

```
itertools.starmap(operator.add, 
                  itertools.izip_longest(self, other, fillvalue=0))
```

This does what I guess your original code is supposed to do.  If you are using Python 3, convert the result to a tuple or list or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: On the other hand, a short and simple statement makes it more clear!

Comment: I don't have a Python 3 interpreter on hand. Is this in Python 3? After a quick search in the docs, I can't find it.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) was introduced in Python 2.6.  What version are you using?

Comment: `TypeError: op_add expected 2 arguments, got 1` I solved this with the `sum()` function instead of `operator.add()`.

Comment: @TylerCrompton: Sorry, fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if I'm totally getting it, but I think the stdlib is your friend:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
dimensions = []
for a, b in izip_longest(self, other, fillvalue=0):
    dimensions.append(a + b)
```

I don't think a list comprehension would be very clean.

Comment: I think this is what the OP wants, though it isn't what the original code does.

Comment: I don't have a Python 3 interpreter on hand. Is this in Python 3? After a quick search in the docs, I can't find it.

Comment: My answer was for 2.7, although it's also in python3 as [`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest). Here's the [docs for 2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for the curious.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the trivial way to use list comprehension, though it's pretty ugly IMHO.

```
dimensions = [
  sum(map(lambda x: ((x is None) and 1 or 2) - 1, (
    self[i] if i<self.numberOfDimensions else None,
    other[i] if i<other.numberOfDimensions else None
  )))

  for i in range(max(self.numberOfDimensions, other.numberOfDimensions))  
]
```

Comment: "Readability counts" indeed. I agree it's ugly, +1 though.

Comment: @TylerCrompton this should work on 2.6 and above, shouldn't it?

Comment: Python 3 doesn't have `xrange()`. Python 3's `range()` is basically equivalent to Python 2's `xrange()`. from what I understand.

Comment: @DorShemer, no my bad for not specifying which version. :)

Answer (score 1):

how about this although untested:

```
dimensions = [sum(map(lambda x: ((x is None) and 1 or 2) - 1, (self[i] if i < self.numberOfDimensions else None, other[i] if i < other.numberOfDimensions else None))) for i in range(max(self.numberOfDimensions, other.numberOfDimensions))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing piece you need is:

```
(a,b) = (self[i] if i < self.numberOfDimensions else None, other[i] if i < other.numberOfDimensions else None)
```

Of course, I'm not convinced that a single expression will be more readable. You might be better off using some kind of map to generate the `(a,b)`s first.